# How to enter text in a div which has type=textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to enter text in a div whose type is textbox.

Refer below HTML snippet of the element before entering the text:

```html
<div class="_5yk2" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="_5rp7">
      <div class="_1p1t">
         <div class="_1p1v" id="placeholder-fr28f" style="white-space: pre- 
            wrap;">Describe your item (optional)
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_5rpb">
         <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_1jt" aria- 
            describedby="placeholder-fr28f" aria-multiline="true" class="notranslate 
            _5rpu" data-testid="status-attachment-mentions-input" role="textbox" 
            spellcheck="true" style="outline: currentcolor none medium; -moz-user- 
            select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;" 
            contenteditable="true">
            <div data-contents="true">
               <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="fr28f" data-offset- 
                  key="496vr-0-0">
                  <div data-offset-key="496vr-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">
                     <span data-offset-key="496vr-0-0">
                     <br data-text="true">
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And after enter the text its look like :

```html
<div class="_5yk2" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="_5rp7">
      <div class="_5rpb">
         <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_1jt" aria- 
            describedby="placeholder-fr28f" aria-multiline="true" class="notranslate 
            _5rpu" data-testid="status-attachment-mentions-input" role="textbox" 
            spellcheck="true" style="outline: currentcolor none medium; -moz-user- 
            select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;" 
            contenteditable="true">
            <div data-contents="true">
               <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="fr28f" data-offset- 
                  key="496vr-0-0">
                  <div data-offset-key="496vr-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">
                     <span data-offset-key="496vr-0-0">
                     <span data-text="true">abhinandan</span>
                     </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So I've tried to set the values as per HTML change using `innerHTML` as below:

```
WebDriverWait waitForDiv= new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var Ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"));
Ele.Click();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
IWebElement myElementRemoveDiv = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("._1p1t"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0])", myElementRemoveDiv);
IWebElement myElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("._1mf > span:nth-child(1)"));
String StrInnerHtml = "<span data-text=\"true\">Entering text</span>";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].innerHTML=" + "'" + StrInnerHtml + "'", myElement);
```

So far above code is successfully able to enter the text but on clicking Next button, the text is not get submitted. Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Where and how is `myElement` defined?

Comment: Sorry my mistake have edited.

Comment: Why didn't `SendKeys()` work?  In my opinion, Selenium is not designed to manipulate the DOM as you are, but to emulate user actions, so I always try to exhaust all the "normal" options before utilising the JS executor like this.

Comment: @C.perk While using SendKeys() i am getting  error Element <div class="_1mf _1mj"> is not reachable by keyboard although i have waited for the element to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not good practice to set the text instead you can directly enter the text. Use CSS path `div[class='notranslate _5rpu'][role='textbox']`

```
IWebElement textbox = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='notranslate _5rpu'][role='textbox']"));
textbox.SendKeys("desired_text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to sendkeys to the below element.

```
IWebElement textBox = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-offset-key='496vr-0-0']"));
textBox.SendKeys("here goes your value")
```

Then check if the Next button is working.

If that does not help, then fire the onchange/keypress event on the element using the below javascript.

To trigger onchange event:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}));",textBox);
```

To trigger keypress event:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}));",textBox);
```

Basically you have to find out the associated event and then dispatch that event. Just change the event as per your element association.